# STS Spring MVC: How to include a JS file in a JSP

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I installed SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.0.
I'm trying to include a JS file in a JSP, using the Spring MVC template as a starting point.
My JSP looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello world!  
</body>
</html>
```

a.js is under src\main\resources and looks like this:

```
window.alert("A");
```

The result is that "Hello world!" gets printed without the alert :-(

I tried putting the JS file in different places, changing the src to be with/without "/", and even adding a servlet-mapping in web.xml to use "default" servlet for "*.js".
Nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp

Comment: STS doesn't really factor in here. You are just trying package a standard java web app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is the js file getting included in your .war file?  I usually put my js and css in src/main/webapp.  something like src/main/webapp/js and src/main/webapp/css.

Secondly, you can reference it appropriately using c:url which will take care of putting the app context on there and stuff.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/a.js" />" />
```

You can use firebug or chrome's developer tools to see if you are getting a 404 for a.js and see what path it is actually requesting.

Comment: Thanks! I used a combination of moving my file to src/main/webapp, using the c:url and adding a servlet-mapping in web.xml to use "default" servlet for "*.js".

Answer (score 3):

I advise placing those js files under *webapp* folder. (I usually put them under *webapp/resources/js*)

And to make this path accessible, I use the **mvc:resources** tag:

> This tag allows static resource requests following a particular URL
>   pattern to be served by a ResourceHttpRequestHandler from any of a
>   list of Resource locations. This provides a convenient way to serve
>   static resources from locations other than the web application root,
>   including locations on the classpath. The cache-period property may be
>   used to set far future expiration headers (1 year is the
>   recommendation of optimization tools such as Page Speed and YSlow) so
>   that they will be more efficiently utilized by the client. The handler
>   also properly evaluates the Last-Modified header (if present) so that
>   a 304 status code will be returned as appropriate, avoiding
>   unnecessary overhead for resources that are already cached by the
>   client. For example, to serve resource requests with a URL pattern of
>   /resources/** from a public-resources directory within the web
>   application root, the tag would be used as follows:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/"/>
```

Source: [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)