# Spring 3.1- javascript file not found- 404 error

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a js file in the folder WebContent/resources/js/test.js. I am trying to include the same file in a jsp. But the jsp file is unable to find the js file (404 error in browser console). I have gone throw couple of questions in SO:

[Can SpringMVC be configured to process all requests, but exclude static content directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234298/can-springmvc-be-configured-to-process-all-requests-but-exclude-static-content)

[Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j)

[STS Spring MVC: How to include a JS file in a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941880/sts-spring-mvc-how-to-include-a-js-file-in-a-jsp)

But still not helping. Here goes my code:

In the application context, i am using the mvc:resource tag.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my jsp

```
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

tried giving src value with

```
 <c:url>
```

too.

my web.xml has

```
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>TestProject</servlet-name> 
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Firebug says

```
The requested resource (/resources/js/test.js) is not available.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The GET request URL in firebug is this

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/resources/js/test.js
```

Is it right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/test.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Spring is trying to find the resource from the container context root, rather than the app context root.

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question, i have tried this. it doesn't help.

Comment: Where is your javascript file located within the project, what's the full path?

Comment: TestProject/WebContent/resources/js/test.js.   TestProject is my project name.

Comment: I'm guessing your mvc:resources bean is having issues with the WebContent folder, try either pointing the location to classpath:/resources/ or moving the resources folder to within the WEB-INF and pointing the location to /WEB-INF/resources/

Comment: Hey it is working fine now. I think it was some problem with contextpath variable declaration!! Sorry for that

Comment: no problem, either accept my answer or post your own and accept it, otherwise this question is going to sit open