# Adding slash after servlet name causes CSS and images not to be loaded

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm setting up a simple servlet to act as a forwarder. Basically so that you can hit the page with this `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/ServletName/foo/bar` instead of like this `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/Main.jsp?par1=foo&par2=bar`

However, it seems to break in a way that I don't even know where to begin looking. It forwards to the page fine when I go to this `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/ServletName`, but when I add anything on the end, it doesn't load any styling or images. Just the text content of the pages.

Anyways, here's my simple servlet

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher( "/main.jsp" ).include( request, response ) ;
}
```

And here is the web xml chunk

```
<servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>Main</display-name>
  <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>package.thing.Main</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Main</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ServletName/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What's happening when I even just add a slash, that would cause it to only load the text of main.jsp, and not the styling or any images?

This works: `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/ServletName`

This breaks: `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/ServletName/`

This also breaks: `http://localhost:8080/WebProjectName/ServletName/why`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlets - Browser can't access css, images when doing a forward to a JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/servlets-browser-cant-access-css-images-when-doing-a-forward-to-a-jsp)

Comment: Do you mean to invoke `include` rather than `forward`?

Answer (score 0):

well you need put  `../css`, if because you use `/your_uri/`
this means if you have `WebContent/css/file.css`

to : `/your_uri/` `css = href="../css/file.css"`

to : `/your_uri/?par=my_thing`  `css = href="../css/file.css`

to : `/your_uri` `css = href="css/file.css"`