# In eclipse dynamic web project, how to link css to jsp file in webcontent folder

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

In Eclipse, I created a Dynamic Web Project and a JSP file under WebContent folder. I also created a CSS file under the WebContent folder. Then I use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="XXX.css">` in the JSP to link to the CSS file but when I run on web server (Tomcat) the CSS didn't apply. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735)

Answer (score 24):

You must put your web project name before the address path of your css file

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/YourProjectName/XXX.css" type="text/css">
```

or in more dynamic way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/XXX.css" />
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use: With style.css file in WEB-INF/jsp folder

```
<style type="text/css">
  <%@include file="css/style.css" %>
</style>
```

**NOTE**

> This however copies the entire source of the CSS file into the HTML
>   output of the JSP page. In other words, this is a server-side include,
>   not a client-side resource reference. So you effectively miss the
>   advantage that the browser can cache static resources and this way you
>   end up with a bandwidth waste because the very same CSS file is
>   embedded in every single page. In other words, a bad idea in terms of
>   performance and efficiency.

as @BalusC described in comment! you want to test your style.css file **anyway**, this is a solution.

Comment: This however copies the entire source of the CSS file into the HTML output of the JSP page. In other words, this is a server-side include, not a client-side resource reference. So you effectively miss the advantage that the browser can cache static resources and this way you end up with a bandwidth waste because the very same CSS file is embedded in every single page. In other words, a bad idea in terms of performance and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restart eclipse so that it maps all css and javascript files again.
I worked for me.