# Unable to access common content in servlet to jsp call

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have scenario where, i need to call a jsp from a servlet and pass a hashmap containing custom objects whose details jsp needs to display...(this is working fine using Request Dispatcher and jstl in jsp code)

however my jsp includes some other jsps that define the look and feel of the whole application.

my structure is as:

TestProject
`<Tabs>`- images
`<Tabs><Tabs>`* background.jpg 
`<Tabs>`- jsp 
`<Tabs><Tabs>` * common 
`<Tabs><Tabs><Tabs>`+ common.jsp
`<Tabs><Tabs>` * xml 
`<Tabs><Tabs><Tabs>` + XMLDisplay.jsp

my XMLDisplay.jsp includes common.jsp which in turn has path for background.

the common.jsp is common to all other files in application and is working fine.... but not in XMLDisplay.jsp.

i have displayed the context path and the servlet path in XMLDisplay.jsp and its fine. (same as in other files) however for images the path somehow is getting distorted. 
and the images are getting accessed from 
http:localhost:8080\images\background.jpg 
instead of 
http:localhost:8080\TestProject\images\background.jpg

the only difference in the other pages is that the call is from one jsp to another while here the call is from servlet to jsp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jstl tag `<c:url value="\images\background.jpg" var="image1"/>` from taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

You should prefer this tag for resources like (*.js, images, etc.) and for constructing links with parameters.

Comment: i cannot make any changes to the code that accesses the images... its a common code being used by others too....

Comment: i want to know what is the difference between a call from jsp to jsp and servlet to jsp. One difference i see is the heirarchy of calling servlet. bt in that case the servlet path and context are still the same once the request dispatcher has forwarded the request to jsp. then y is the relative path changing.