# Use relative path for form actions in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

How to use relative path in form action

```
<form action="/myapp/alterPassword" id="changepassword" method="post"
        autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return checkPassword();">
        <div
            style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 35%; width: 480px;">
```

In the above code is there any way to use relative path instead of the myapp/alterPassword ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just dynamically print the context path as follows:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/alterPassword" ...>
```

Or use the HTML `<base>` tag so that all relative links in the page are relative to it.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735)

Comment: Thank you so much! After trying out a lot of different things this finally worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `../` or use context path as follows

```
<form action="/<%=request.getContextPath()%>/alterPassword" id="changepassword" method="post"
        autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return checkPassword();">
```