# Cannot load static contents in simple java webapp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have Java web app with following structure

```
WebContent->images->image.jpg
          ->js->test.js
```

I tried displaying an image in my jsp with the following code.

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/image.jpg" width="500" height="500" />
```

Firebug shows a GET request with the below URL

```
 http://localhost:8080/test/images/image.jpg
```

With a 200 ok response, but displays nothing.

I checked these questions:

[Unable to load static contents (Images/JS) in web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509056/unable-to-load-static-contents-images-js-in-web-application)

[Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

But didn't help. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

My servlet mapping

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.test.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: did you try accessing the image directly from the browser? as in load "http://localhost:8080/test/images/image.jpg" in browser.

Comment: Yes, I get the page for localhost:8080/test/ with a 200 ok response. I will post my servlet mapping if that helps..

Comment: could you try changing the url-pattern to "<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>"

Comment: It works!! can you post it as answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your servlet is catching all the request and passing it to the HelloServlet.

You need to avoid giving "`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`".

try changing the url-pattern to "`<url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>`"