# Java: Returning a relative URL from a Java class?

Tags: java, jsp, url, jstl

I have some images stored in /images the problem is that i wish to return a url like so from a class.

```
/images/test.png
```

The problem is that in my development machine my url is in the form of

```
http://localhost/myApp
```

and in production its in the form of

```
http://www.mysite.com
```

so i can't just return /images as this doesn't work on the development machine

I suppose what i am trying to do in Java is the same as teh JSTL tag does

```
<c:url
```

So when i am in my development machine it would return

```
/myApp/images/test.png
```

and in production

```
/images/test.png
```

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getContextPath()` method on the `ServletRequest` - and then append the rest of your path:

```
String url = request.getContextPath() + "/images/test.png";
```

Comment: Thanks, but its a standard java STATIC method hence i don't have request, is there a work around?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Only the actual request knows what the context path is.  You need to design your method in such a way as to give it access to the `request` or possibly pass the value of `request.getContextPath()` into that method as a "base path".

Answer (score 3):

```
${request.contextPath}/images/foo
```

You're probably looking for the [context path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath%28%29).