# Where to put images when using Tomcat?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j)

I know this question is asked again and again, but I just couldn't get this to work.

[folder structure http://kauko.pingtimeout.net/venttiCap.JPG](http://kauko.pingtimeout.net/venttiCap.JPG)

I have my images in the WebContent/kuvat/ folder. I also put one of the images directly into the WebContent folder (hertta1.gif). But when I try to use the images like this

```
<img src="kuvat/hertta1.gif" /> or <img src="hertta1.gif" />
```

nothing happens. The kuvat/*gif request results in a 404, while the other one is apparently an empty response.

GameServlet is the only Servlet, and it's mapped to '/'. So when using the application I use the address "http://localhost:8080/VenttiWeb/"

I'm using Tomcat7

Comment: You're right. It's pretty much an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<img src="/kuvat/hertta1.gif" /> or <img src="/hertta1.gif" />
```

Also, it may not be a good idea to hardcode the context path. In a JSP you might try something like:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/kuvat/hertta1.gif"/>
```

And something similar can be done from a servlet using ServletContext instead of a PageContext.

Reference: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ResourceUrlProblems

Comment: This wasn't exactly the right answer, but I marked it anyway since it helped me find my problem. I only had one servlet, which was mapped to '/'. When I changed it to '/Game', everything started working. Could anyone explain why it works like that?

Comment: When you map your servlet to '/' it takes the place of the default servlet, which is responsible for sending static content. Since I assume your servlet didn't extend or otherwise implement the functionality of the default servlet, Tomcat couldn't serve the static content correctly. Default servlet doc: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html