# how should I get root folder path in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I want to retrieve root path of webapplication, then I want to append link to root path.
I tried request.context but it returns "http://localhost:8080/webapp/web-inf".

For example my root folder path is

```
path  =  http://localhost:8080/webapp/
```

and I want to append remaining link to this path

```
helpPath= /help/page/help.htm


<a  href="${path} + ${helpPath}" target="_blank">name</a>
```

Any help or pointer really appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>
```

will give you the rootpath of your application so in your case it will be http://localhost:8080/webapp

As per comment:

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/help/page/help.htm
```

will give you your page

Comment: and thats what you need right, so you if you say <%=request.getContextPath()%>/help/page/help.htm you will be able to navigate to your page

Comment: I write down following code <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>${helpPath}" target="_blank">name</a>    It works. Thanks For your details help.

Comment: Scriptlets are soo 90's. OP was already using EL in first place. Why falling back to obsolete technology?

Answer (score 14):

You can use pageContext.request.contextPath

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

So you can use,

```
<a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${helpPath}" target="_blank">name</a>
```

But the better way is to set the base href to this path and then use the path as it is.

```
<head>

        <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">

    </head>
<body>
<a  href="${helpPath}" target="_blank">name</a>

</body>
```

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath} + ${helpPath}` will not concat

Comment: Good answer. Base href can only better be really absolute (i.e. start with `http://`). Otherwise older IE versions may do weird things.

Comment: @BalusC Wow, BalusC said it is good answer, I will take that as accepted answer :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method of the ServletContext.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
<c:url>
```

jstl tag. It will add the context path for you.

Answer (score 0):

`<%=request.getContextPath()%>` will give `/webapp`

So your link should look like :

```
<a  href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>${helpPath}" target="_blank">name</a>
```