# how should I define a path in jsp where my .js & css is located in different location

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I have a bunch of jsp files, js files and css files. All these files are placed in tomcat server in webapps directory. So presently in my current project I have jsp's are located in one location and js, css are located in different location as shown in below image. Can anyone help me how to include the js path as relative path.

[image]

So please give me some suggestions where the path should be in relative.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327390/how-should-i-get-root-folder-path-in-jsp-page

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by just specifying as below in my jsp.

```
/...
```

When we specify / it goes back to ROOT directory.

Here is the code snippet.

```
<link href="/resource2/765432/myproject/css/myproject.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Thanks for helping and if anyone needs any help on this, I am ready to help.