# Servlet Url Mapping Error

Tags: servlets

I cannot figure out why my servlet isn't mapped corectly.

This is part of the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlets.InsertServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/insert</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will generate: localhost:8080/GestiuneSimpozioane/jsp/insert (Because the form where I send the data is located in a jsp folder)
Instead I need:  localhost:8080/GestiuneSimpozioane/insert

How shall I modify the mapping ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the servlet mapping. Your problem is how you specified the servlet URL in the HTML form. Given the symptoms you have used

```
<form action="insert">
```

Relative URLs in HTML (i.e. ones not starting with a scheme or a `/`) will be resolved relative to the URL of the requested HTML page (as appears in the browser's address bar). This is in your case apparently in the `/jsp` subfolder. The browser will then of course interpret the URL being in the `/jsp` folder.

You need to specify a domain-relative URL instead.

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/insert">
```

The `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` will dynamically print the context path and hence the HTML will in your case be generated as follows:

```
<form action="/GestiuneSimpozioane/insert">
```

You can also achieve this with the `<base>` tag. See also [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735).

If you *really* need the servlet to listen on `/jsp/insert` instead for some reason, then just alter the `<url-pattern>` accordingly. Don't forget to take this into account in the HTML `<form>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, "that's what it will generate"?

Use an absolute, not relative, path in the form. You should probably use JSTL's `<c:url>` tag to automagically include the context etc., too.