# How to get resource in WEB-INF JSP/Struts

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

There are JSP pages in a folder called 'jsp' inside the `WEB-INF`. Those pages need some javascript files. In JSP page, javascript files are called

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../app.lib/jQuery-v-1-7-2.js"></script>
```

but the browser cannot access this resource. All requests to the JSP pages inside the web-inf go through an action and seperate name space also has been given for that pages called 'secure'.

Lets say that, this account.jsp page needs a javascript file which locates in a folder called 'app.lib' inside the 'web' folder.(out of web-inf) .

**(1)**  I want to know a way to retrieve that javascript file into account.jsp page using struts actions or another jsp functionality.
**(2)** second question is: Lets say, there are images which should be secured, and the application itself should be able to send them to the browser when requested.In other words, images inside a folder in WEB-INF, then how can I access them in account.jsp?
This is the web.xml(session configuration and welcome file list tags removed for clear view)
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app.......>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>

        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>`

This is the project structure
[image]

Comment: In my case static content was deployed as a separate project. <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/csa/javascript/equipment.js"></script>

Comment: In the JSP page, get the context path of your web application. From there you can go down to the javascript folder.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV. Thanks for your attention. Would you explain it more using this project structure with sample code? it is not clear that u mentioned " seperate project " .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j)

Comment: @BaluC: Look like same thing. But not.**Two things**

Answer (score -1):

Don't put your JavaScript files inside the WEB-INF folder. JSP pages kept in WEB-INF are accessed by the servlet-container, processed, and then rendered to the client via the servlet, which has access to files in WEB-INF. JavaScript files are client side resources, and since the client side cannot access any resources inside WEB-INF, they must be located outside that folder.

Typically, it's common to put your JavaScript files in a folder called "js", like so:

```
-/js
    - actions.js
-/WEB-INF
    - /jsp
        - abc.jsp
```

As an aside, since JavaScript is client side, even if you were to go through the trouble of storing them in the WEB-INF folder and using the servlet engine to process them, any user would still be able to access the resource URL and view the source. Essentially, you gain no benefit from this and only incur costs, both in maintenance and additional development overhead.

Comment: Thanks Mr jmort253. what you say is 100% right. then, according to your given project structure, would you let me know how to call that actions.js by abc.jsp? When the user is in abc.jsp page the browser shows the URL as `http://localhost:8084/app/secure/user`. Then how the browser calls to that actions.js is `http://localhost:8084/app/secure/actions.js`. This doesn't get the javascript file.

Comment: @AashMaharoon - Without seeing your servlet configuration from web.xml, I can only speculate, but it seems to me that /app or /app/secure most likely routes to your controllers, where Struts then handles forwarding to a JSP view. Instead, your JavaScript files are accessed directly from the folder. So something like `http://localhost:8084/app/js/actions.js` or `http://localhost:8084/js/actions.js` would likely work. You'll have to play around with this in your address bar to find out how your project is structured.