# Refer to css from jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp, href

I have jsp page under `WebContent/WEB-INF/forms/login.jsp` -

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=/Styles/Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Create new customer</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`Site.css` is located in `WebContent/Styles` . When I load `login.jsp` I see that the css doesn't affects . How write the `href` correctly?

Comment: What is the full path for the Site.css file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
```

or if your page is in http://yoursite.com/path/to/WebContent/WEB-INF/forms/login.jsp, you can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/WebContent/Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: In Java, WEB-INF is a protected directory. The `../../` trick need not work!