# How to handle paths in this case

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have the following sturcture in my app

```
--Controller
  |_ServletA
  |_ServletB
--Webpages
  |_Secure
      |_PageA
      |_PageB
  |_PageC
```

Now  the application starts with PageC which posts to ServletB.The ServletB forwards to PageA.

Now from PageA a link is clicked which points to ServletB . The servletB does some work and forwards to PageB.At this stage the address on the url is  `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/Secure/PageB.jsp.`

Here is the problem now a link on PageB points back to ServletB. The link is

```
<a href="ServletB">
```

Therefore the browser points to `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/Secure/ServletB` which is wrong as it should be `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/ServletB`.
How can I fix this problem without changing the link to ServletB from pageB, Since it works okay in first attempt but when the relative address changes it fails ?

EDIT :

In short what I want to know is what should i place in the link

```
<a href="ServletB">
```

so that if the relative address is `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/Secure/` it points to `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/ServletB` instead of `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/Secure/ServletB` and if the relative address is `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/` it takes it to the same location `http://localhost:8080/MyApp-war/ServletB`

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question? How are you mapping your servlet url, the url should be static.

Comment: I just added an edit. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: I know but the relative address is causing an issue initially it was being called from http:.../MyApp-war/ which works but then its being called from MyApp-war/Secure/ which then gives an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access CSS and images when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do here is to add the context path of your web application to the link. You can do something like this;

This means, if your servlet definition in your `web.xml` is like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myfullpackage.MyServletB</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletB</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You will do something like this

```
<a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ServletB'>
```

or you use expression language form

```
<a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ServletB'>
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Could you tell me what exactly is the difference b/w context path and relative path ?

Comment: You are welcome. Relative path in my own understanding deals with the location of a resource based on another resource. For example, if the path of `file1` is `/opt/myfiles/file1` and `file2` is in `/opt/myfiles/web/file2`. The location of `file1` relative to `file2` is `../file1`. This means you are not referring to the absolute location of `file1` which is  `/opt/myfiles/file1`.

Comment: For context path, this is the root path of your web application. It is the base path used to locate other resources resources in a web application.