# How to get only part of URL from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, string, url, servlets, httprequest

From the following URL I need to get `(http://localhost:9090/dts)` alone.
That is I need to remove `(documents/savedoc)` (OR)
   need to get only - `(http://localhost:9090/dts)`

```
http://localhost:9090/dts/documents/savedoc
```

Is there any method available in request to get the above?

I tried the following and got the result. But still trying.

```
System.out.println("URL****************"+request.getRequestURL().toString());  
System.out.println("URI****************"+request.getRequestURI().toString());
System.out.println("ContextPath****************"+request.getContextPath().toString());

URL****************http://localhost:9090/dts/documents/savedoc  
URI****************/dts/documents/savedoc  
ContextPath****************/dts
```

Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK for this there is no API provided method, need to customization.

```
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int portNumber = request.getServerPort();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
```

// try this

```
System.out.println(serverName + ":" +portNumber + contextPath );
```

Answer (score 41):

You say you want to get exactly:

```
http://localhost:9090/dts
```

In your case, the above string consists of:

1. [**scheme**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme): *http*
2. **server [host name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)**: *localhost*
3. **server [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking))**: *9090*
4. [**context path**](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#setting-context-path): *dts*

More info about the elements of a request path can be found in the official Oracle *Java EE Tutorial*: [Getting Information from Requests](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets005.htm#BNAFW)

### First variant:

```
String scheme = request.getScheme();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int serverPort = request.getServerPort();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();  // includes leading forward slash

String resultPath = scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + contextPath;
System.out.println("Result path: " + resultPath);
```

### Second variant:

```
String scheme = request.getScheme();
String host = request.getHeader("Host");        // includes server name and server port
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();  // includes leading forward slash

String resultPath = scheme + "://" + host + contextPath;
System.out.println("Result path: " + resultPath);
```

---

Both variants will give you what you wanted: `http://localhost:9090/dts`

Of course, there are other variants like others already wrote. It's just in your original question you asked about how to get `http://localhost:9090/dts`, i.e. you want your path to **include** the *scheme*.

But if you don't need the *scheme*, the quick way is:

```
String resultPath = request.getHeader("Host") + request.getContextPath();
```

And you'll get (in your case): `localhost:9090/dts`

Answer (score 18):

Just remove URI from URL and then append context path to it. No need to fiddle with loose schemes and ports which is only more tedious when you're dealing with default port `80` which don't need to appear in URL at all.

```
StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String ctx = request.getContextPath();
String base = url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length() + ctx.length());
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal) (for the JSP/JSTL variant of composing the base URL)

Comment: 5 similar questions.  Finally an answer that is succinct.

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding, you need the domain part and Context path only. Based on this understanding, You can use this method to get the required string.

```
String domain = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String cpath = request.getContextPath().toString();

String tString = domain.subString(0, domain.indexOf(cpath));

tString = tString + cpath;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to get, in their **endpoint**, the **URL of the front page** which targeted the endpoint. You can use this:

```java
request.getHeader("referer")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I have a method like this:

```
public String getAbsoluteContextPath() throws MalformedURLException {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest();
    URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    return url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + context.getRequestContextPath();
}
```

This method will return what you want, with the port number only if it exists in the current request. In your case it will return: http://localhost:9090/dts