# How to fetch localhost:8080 from full URL

Tags: java, http

I have a URL path as http://localhost:8080/welcome/this/is/a/test

My line in Java is

```
String domain = httpServletRequest.getServerName();
```

But with this I get "localhost". I want the port number as well
I want to get only "localhost:8080" in my string.

Comment: Why not call `getServerPort` and concatenate the two results into one string?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065257/how-to-get-only-part-of-url-from-httpservletrequest (already retracted a misplaced vote, so can't vote again)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved in one line of code

```
String hostName = request.getHeader("host");
System.out.println(" HostName : " + hostName);
```