# How to handle relative path in JSP and Servlet and AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have folder structure like shown below,

```
web
|_Lib
|   |_lib.js
|_Images
|   |_Image1
|_ Folder_1
|   |_ Folder_1_page1 (Includes Page 2) (Displaying Image using lib.js from folder Images)
|_ Page1 (Includes Page 2) (Displaying Image using lib.js from folder Images)
|_ Page2
```

My Question is
How to handle relative path/Context path while calling pages as shown above

If I am On root folders "page1", it calls page2 from same folder which displays image from Images folder
but
If I am On Folder_1_Page1 page then it calls page2 from root folder which unable to display image

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal) Note that this has technically nothing to do with ajax.