# Struts2 Accessing files in the web content

Tags: java, file, struts2, directory

Let's say I have this given namespace or url like this

```
http://localhost:8090/MyApp/pageowner/profile?id=1
```

where in that page or `profile` has an img tag.

and the path of the image being retrieved is like this

```
media/user_01/photos/imm_2011_01_06_17_48_32_332.JPG
```

Where the media folder is located Web-Content.

so if I just want to access the file itself I could just do this

```
http://localhost:8090/MyApp/media/user_01/photos/imm_2011_01_06_17_48_32_332.JPG
```

but how come when I am inside the `pageowner` namespace I could not access it. the url being returned is like this

```
 http://localhost:8090/HitPlay/pageowner/media/user_01/photos/imm_2011_01_06_17_48_32_332.JPG
```

That gives me an error 404 not found.

it is not accessing the file in the root context or Web-Content. is there anyway I can specify that the file I am getting is in the root or Web content location if I am inside the `pageowner` namespace

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using `request.getContextPath()` - it is used to return the portion of the request URL and specifies the context of the request.