# How to correct URL mapping in web.xml file

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Here's my scenario...My homepage link is

```
local/proj/admin-home
```

when I browse in another link like

```
local/proj/registration/organization-registry
```

but on that page when I hover my mouse in another link the link gives me

```
local/proj/registration/list
```

But this link must be

```
local/proj/list
```

So I noticed that when I browse to the link local/proj/registration/organization-registry all of the links in that page also starts with local/proj/registration/ but it must be /local/proj/ only...

here's my xml file

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>admin-home</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>web.HomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>admin-home</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/admin-home</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>list</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ViewRegisteredServlet.RegisteredOrganizationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>list</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/list</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>organization-registry</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>web_registration.OrganizationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>organization-registry</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/registration/organization-registry</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You was apparently using a relative link. A relative link is a link which does not start with the scheme (e.g. `http://`), nor with a forward slash `/` which would take you to the domain root.

```
<a href="list">list</a>
```

Such a link is relative to the current URL (as you see in browser's address bar). So it's basically pointing to the resource in the same folder.

You actually need to go one folder up:

```
<a href="../list">list</a>
```

Or, better, make it domain-relative, so that you don't need to mess with links whenever you move resources around.

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/list">list</a>
```

This all has nothing to do with your servlet mappings. This is just a basic web development concept.

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

Comment: Im using one page for all the menus in all of the page. So I just need to put ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ in all of my links?

Comment: Technically, yes the most robust way is to prepend all your webapp-specific links with the context path. See also the "see also" link for tips how to make this less bloated.

Comment: one more thing how can I implement this if Im redirecting the page through my servlet? For example resp.sendRedirect("admin-home");

Comment: Just use `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/admin-home")`. Note that many if not all Java EE based MVC frameworks take this transparently into account, e.g. JSF.