# c:url tag includes jsession id query string

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, contextpath

What is the best way of obtaining context-root on a jsp page. If I hardcode my css/image to "/myapp/images/foo.gif" then it will be a broken link if the context root / app name is changed. Using relative path is not always preferrable because a context root can be multi-path (eg: /mysite/myapp)

So far I've tried using `<c:url var="root" value="/"/>` which works alright (`${root}` will give the context-root `/myapp/`), however if this is the very first time user is visiting the site (or if cookie is cleaned on the browser), the value assigned to `${root}` became something like `/myapp/;jsessionid=019762g1hk3781kh98uihilho` and it breaks the images/css reference. Is there any other better way than this?

Comment: Note: that's not a query string, that's an URI path fragment. A query string is the part after `?` in URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *So far I've tried using `<c:url var="root" value="/"/>` which works alright (${root} will give the context-root /myapp/)*

This is not the right way. The `<c:url>` should be applied on *every single* URL **individually**.

You'd better use

```html
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)