# How to connect CSS files to my JSP pages stored in Web-Content (Dynamic Web Project)

Tags: css, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm quite new to the Spring|Hibernate|Eclipse setup. For some reason, My index.jsp files are not picking on the css files (css & css01).

Any clue why?

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_switcher.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css01/job_blue.responsive.css" title="job_blue" type="text/css">
```

Comment: What is the full URL of the JSP file as you see in browser's address bar? What is the full URL of the CSS file as you see in browser's address bar while retrieving the CSS file individually? Once you know/mention both, the proper relative URL for the CSS file for usage in the `<link>` element of the JSP file can easily be extracted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided the **end tag** of the `link` tag. Provide it like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_switcher.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css01/job_blue.responsive.css" title="job_blue" type="text/css" />
```

**OR**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_switcher.css" type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css01/job_blue.responsive.css" title="job_blue" type="text/css"></link>
```

Comment: Why two -ves without comments? If the `DOCTYPE` IS `XHTML`, you should have end tag. It must be properly closed - Have a look at the reference - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: great catch @Ravindra Gullapalli