# Are there any standard JSP EL function as analog of JSTL c:url?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, el

I found this code VERY ugly:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/my/path/${id}.html'/>">Title</a>
```

in:

```
href="<c:url value=
```

and:

```
'/>">
```

parts. Are there any standard function available from JSP EL, which do same job as JSTL **c:out**, but look like:

```
<a href="${f:context('/my/path/'.concat(id).concat('.html'))">Title</a>
```

or better:

```
<a href="${f:context}/my/path/${id}.html">Title</a>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for great link! I study question about using **base** HTML tag but found that it have a lot of pitfall as according to W3C spec it require *absolute* path which un-excepted as we use load balance proxy... +1

Comment: That answer also shows how to generate the right one.

Comment: Thanks! I see **req.requestURL** in **base** tag ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Or better:*
>
> ```
> <a href="${f:context}/my/path/${id}.html">Title</a>
> ```

This is possible:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/my/path/${id}.html">Title</a>
```

If you find it lengthy, just alias it with a `<c:set>` elsewhere in top of your master template like so

```
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" scope="request" />
```

so that you can use it anywhere else like

```
<a href="${ctx}/my/path/${id}.html">Title</a>
```

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
<c:url value='/my/path/${id}.html' var="myUrl"/>
<a href="${myUrl}">My Url</a>
```

This will store the URL in the variable `myUrl`, which can be used as expression in the `a` tag.

Comment: thanks for answer, look to my answer, where I put a bit more options. One drawback - you must put **c:url var= value=** at the beginning of each JSP files... +1

Answer (score 1):

My study on this field shown me that I can put **ctx** parameter in own EE filter in **web.xml**:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ctxFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.my.web.filter.CtxFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ctxFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and:

```
public class CtxFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) { }
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("CTX", request.getServletContext().getContextPath());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

or in Spring interceptor (based on my project framework stack). Also this can be done by:

```
<spring:url value="/" var="ctx" htmlEncoding="true"/>
<a href="${ctx}/path/...">...</a>
```

or as:

```
<c:url value="/" var="ctx"/>
<a href="${ctx}/path/...">...</a>
```

but fist line of these examples must be duplicated across JSP files.

And finally you can implement TDL file with appropriate function **WEB-INF/tlds/ctx.tld**:

```
<function>
    <name>ctx</name>
    <function-class>org.my.web.Ctx</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String getCtx()</function-signature>
</function>
```

Reference:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html