# Map with @WebServlet url pattern annotation in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

When trying to make a simple webservlet a stumble upon this problem: if I use a name that includes /../ it won't find the resource.

This is what I have that WORKS:

Controller.java

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/Controller"})
public class Controller extends HttpServlet{ ... }
```

And the JSP-page:

```
<form action="Controller">
...
</form>
```

However, what I try to do specify the name as a folder, to work more structured. This is the code I struggle with and that DOESN'T work:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/servletController/Controller"})
public class Controller extends HttpServlet{ ... }
```

JSP-page:

```
<form action="/servletController/Controller">
...
</form>
```

And I tried numerous variations. So my question, how to properly use a folder-structure with the urlPatters-annotation, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the leading slash you specified in the `<form action>`. It makes the specified URL domain-relative. I.e. it's resolved relative to the domain root in the URL as you see in browser's address bar, instead of to the currently requested path (folder) in the URL as you see in browser's address bar.

Imagine that your JSP is opened by

```
http://localhost:8080/contextname/some.jsp
```

and the URL has thus the folder `/contextname` in it. The form action as you have would submit to

```
http://localhost:8080/servletController/Controller
```

while the servlet is as per your mapping *actually* at the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/contextname/servletController/Controller
```

Fix the form action accordingly to make it path-relative instead of domain-relative:

```
<form action="servletController/Controller">
```

Or, by specifying a valid domain-relative URL:

```
<form action="/contextpath/servletController/Controller">
```

Or, if you worry about the dynamicness of the context path and rather like not to hardcode it:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servletController/Controller">
```

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned: I tried without the leading slash, but still had the same error ---

HTTP Status 404 - /WebApp-Test/servletController/Confirm.jsp
type Status report
message /WebApp-Test/servletController/Confirm.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 --- Does it matter that the controller.java-code is in a specific package

Comment: The `/WebApp-Test/servletController/Confirm.jsp` does not seem to be a valid servlet URL, no. Why are you using `<form action="servletController/Confirm.jsp">` instead of `<form action="servletController/Controller">` as mapped in your servlet? Or perhaps you fiddled too much and actually aren't running the code you think you're running and thus you need to clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart?

Comment: Ow shoot! That's because the controller sends my code to new JSP-pages like Confirm.jsp. So the new problem lies further in my code. But at least the first part is solved by using the code without leading slash (like you suggested). Thx!