# MIME Issue: When RequestDispatcher is used to forward a request from a Servlet to a JSP page, the CSS and Javascript of that JSP page aren't loading

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm calling a servlet from a `JSP` page and setting some Attributes in servlet and finally calling ANOTHER `JSP` using RequestDispatcher's forward method. The second `JSP` is loading, showing the attributes that I've passed to it but none of the STYLESHEETS or `jQuery/JAVASCRIPT` files are loading into the page.

Error Msg: Upon Element Inspection in Mozilla of the forwarded JSP page I'm getting following error msg .

> The stylesheet .../java/tutorial/mystyle.css was not loaded because
>   its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

And for javascript its showing `SYNTAX ERROR` msg.

Without this forwarding if the JSP page is run, both the CSS and JavaScript called on this page are loading.

I've tried adding mime-mapping in my `web.xml` for css but still its not working.

I tried calling the second JSP page separately without servlet forwarding everything is working fine, stylesheets and javascripts are all loading.

How can I load my CSS and Javascript during Request forwarding ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get your paths right. Duplicate of [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, you solved my problem  :-)