# jsp The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, scriptlet

I am using the eclipse helper for Java EE development.
I am developing a Struts web application.
In a JSP page I use code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%out.print(getServletContext().getContextPath());%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%out.print(getServletContext().getContextPath());%>/css/home.css" />
```

When I run my server this page works correctly. However, Eclipse shows an error on `getServletContext()`

> The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type 
>    __2F_Compiler_2F_WebContent_2F_pages_2F_home_2E_jsp

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Because the page works correctly, I'd like to hide this error in Eclipse. How can I do that?

Comment: If Eclipse shows an error it is almost sure that you have a problem. You shouldn't hide it.

Comment: but i'm get my context path correctly and .js ans .css files loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak for Eclipse's mistake, but in this specific case, you should be using the implicit JSP scriptlet variable `application` and not be using `HttpServlet`-inherited methods.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%out.print(application.getContextPath());%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%out.print(application.getContextPath());%>/css/home.css" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this is a 90's way of writing JSPs which is [officially discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) since JSP 2.0 which was released more than a decade ago. Are you sure you're reading up to date resources while learning JSP? You should be using EL expressions instead.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/home.css" />
```

Or, via `<c:set>` to save the boilerplate:

```html
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="${root}/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${root}/css/home.css" />
```

#### See also:

- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat 6.0, you should add extended Servlet.

> Project->Properties->Add Library->Server Runtime

And it will add the apache's lib.