# Can tag file take another tag as an attribute?

Tags: jsp, url, parameter-passing, jsp-tags

I have a form in a tag file with the action url expected as an attribute.

```
<%@ attribute name="action" required="true" %>
<form action="${action}"...
```

But when used in a following manner `c:url` is passed as a string literal.

```
<t:a-form action="<c:url value='/a'/>"/>
```

I came up with a workaround:

```
<c:url value="/a" var="a"/>
<t:a-form action="${a}"/>
```

Do I have to use auxiliary variable?

Comment: It is what it is. What task exactly of <c:url> are you primarily interested in? Then you can just substitute that in EL so you don't need <c:url> anymore.

Comment: I need it to add application context to the url. Why it doesn't work with custom tag but works on the html form tag directly?

Comment: Because it's not legal syntax. Is this helpful in solving your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3658735

Comment: EL workaround is better then mine and technically doesn't require auxiliary variable. But I mainly interested why it's imposible pass tag into tag. Can you elaborate what you mean by illegal syntax? I know that attribute is `String` type by default. But how does this hinders evaluation?