# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I am running a Spring MVC application and below is my Project Structure.

[image]

In my `homepage.jsp` , I have tried to load the js in the header section.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/myScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

But I am getting the below error in the browser.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404?
```

In my spring file, I have added

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Can somebody point me to the error I am making?

Comment: can you show your servletcontext.xml !!

Comment: What is your URL for accessing the `homepage.jsp` in your browser? If something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/homepage.jsp`, then `myapp` is the "context path" of your application, and all absolute paths have to list that, e.g. `src="/resources/myScript.js"` should be `src="/myapp/resources/myScript.js"` when seen by the browser. Do not hardcode that value in your .jsp files, because it can change. There are many good articles about this if you search for them.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for the help. It helps me resolve the problem.

Comment: Use like this core jstl library <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/myStyle.css" />" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use Core JSTL to provide resource path in JSP and also define mvc resources in XML so that any mvc interceptor won't be applicable to resources' request.

```
<!-- UI resources exclusions from servlet mapping -->
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

and use core jstl to load resource file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/myScript.js'/>"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the actual path of the JS file in your WAR file. Check if you can access the JS file directly by calling its URL. For example - http://localhost:8080/YOURWARNAME/resources/myScript.js. Then include the script file in JSP with the EL ${pageContext.request.contextPath}. Like this

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/myScript.js"></script>
```

More details in a similar issue - [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)