# Unable to call servlet from form action

Tags: java, forms, servlets, url-pattern

I have a form in which I want to submit request to a servlet called registrationServlet.The register servlet is under a directory called "Controller". But it fails to access the servlet after submitting the form. How can I resolve this issue? I get the following error after submitting the form

> HTTP Status 404 - /ClassProject/Views/RegisterServlet
>
> description : The requested resource is not available.

form : **(Form resides in Login.jsp page under Views directory)**

```
    <form action="RegisterServlet" class="register" method="POST" >
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration</legend>
            Username : <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </br></br>

            Password : <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </br></br>
            Email : <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </br></br>
            Date of Birth : <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
            </br></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my directory structure :

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: editer the post . please check

Comment: The problem is you are using relative path in the form action add the context root to your action value.

Comment: there is something wrong as you are getting `/ClassProject/Views/RegisterServlet`  error

Comment: The problem lies in your project structure. Go through the link as @KarthikeyanVaithilingam suggested.

Comment: @AL-zami was your problem solved ?

Comment: @Ravi yes problem already been solved. The link pinned above my post provided the solution.Thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
<form action="RegisterServlet" class="register" method="POST" >
```

to

```
<form action="../RegisterServlet" class="register" method="POST" >
```

Because, your `Login.jsp` resides under `Views` folder and you are trying to access `RegisterServlet` in same path. And, that's why request is going to

```
/ClassProject/Views/RegisterServlet
```

instead of

```
 /ClassProject/RegisterServlet
```

But, as per `web.xml` this servlet exists at project root.

Comment: This will work but i recommend not to use relative path. Use `<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/RegisterServlet">` by this way it will work even the JSP is been forwarded from a servlet.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I'm not sure about `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` could you explain me how does it move the request ?? I mean, how does it know whether it has to go to `../../` or `../`. Imagine you have `/ClassProject/Views/RegisterServlet` and `/ClassProject/Views/something/RegisterServlet`. Then, your `login.jsp` is at `/ClassProject/Views/else/login.jsp` ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal/3658735#3658735