# Spring boot no mapping for CSS - JS

Tags: spring-boot

**My project structure:**

```
resoureces
  static
    css
    js
  templates
    a.html
    b.html
```

**My application.yml:**

```
resources:
static-locations: classpath:/
```

**And my html code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta content="webkit" name="renderer">
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/img/favicon.ico" />
      <script src="static/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
      <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="static/js/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
      <link href="static/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="static/css/pretty.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="static/css/iconfont.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="static/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="static/css/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <p>test</p>
</body>
```

**My controller:**

```
 @Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String toIndex(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/index/test")
    public String test(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

/index css and js success

but /index/test idea show no mapping for it

What is the correct configuration?

HTML How to link CSS and JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-find-relative-resources-like-css-images-and-links-when-cal)

Comment: Is the problem only with navigation in Idea or it's not working properly when you run the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using relative paths, such as `static/css/reset.css`.

Your browser will handle these by using the current path, and append the relative one.

Assuming that you're running your application on port 8080, when you call `http://localhost:8080/index`, the resources will be fetched from `http://localhost:8080/static/css/reset.css`. However, when you're calling `/index/test`, the relative path would refer to `http://localhost:8080/index/static/css/reset.css`.

That means that due to you using relative paths, it will fetch the resources from a different location if your path is different.

One possible solution is to use a `<base />` tag within the `<head>` section of your HTML, such as:

```html
<base href="/" />
```

By setting the `<base />` tag, you're telling your browser where to relatively fetch resources from.

More detailed information can be found within [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag).

---

Also, be aware that by default, Spring boot will serve resources within `src/main/resources/static` on the context path itself, so might have to drop the `static/` part from the URLs, such as:

```html
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
```