# No mapping for GET /js/home.js

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the same problem as mentioned in
[no mapping for GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003720/spring-boot-no-mapping-for-css-js)
but didn't work for me.

this is the structure :
[resource structure in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRkIS.jpg)

and this is my config class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView getHomepage() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("home.html");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

and I have this in my html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css" />
```

but still get the error:
No mapping for GET /css/home.css
No mapping for GET /js/home.js

would be appreciated for any suggestions
thank you

Comment: solved! I just remove the MvcConfig class :)

Answer (score 0):

this is youre config

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan("directory with youre getHomepage() controller ")
    public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver =
                    new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/"); //youre directory with home.jsp
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }
    }
```

this is youre controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/"})
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```