# Include a private JSP from a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have my Servlet responding on the everything "/" url-pattern. Inside I need to sometimes render html, so I'd like to .include a JSP page, but I'd like that .jsp to be inaccessible externally. Also, how can I pass a model object into it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *I'd like to .include a JSP page, but I'd like that .jsp to be inaccessible externally.*

Put it in `/WEB-INF` folder. The client cannot access it, but the `RequestDispatcher` can access it.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

---

> *Also, how can I pass a model object into it.*

Set it as request attribute.

```
request.setAttribute("bean", bean); // It'll be available as ${bean} in JSP.
```

---

#### See also:

- [Servlets tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) (contains Hello World example and useful links)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523430/hidden-features-of-jsp-servlet)
- [Design patterns webbased applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)

---

That said, be aware that mapping a servlet on `/` takes over the job of servletcontainer's builtin `DefaultServlet` for serving static content. You'll have to handle all static files like JS/CSS/images yourself. Consider choosing a more specific `url-pattern` like `/pages/*` or `*.do` for JSP views. Bring eventually a `Filter` in front as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513).

Comment: I refer putting resources in their own sub folder like (`WEB-INF/jsp`)

Comment: @rsp: You can indeed always categorize it further the way you want :)

Comment: Wasn't my choice on the / servlet - no directories, no extensions. Your answer worked once I added a /WEB-INF/jsp/* mapping to org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet

Comment: You're welcome. As to the extra mapping: that's weird. It should by default work out of the box. Was the servletcontainer's builtin `JspServlet` in servletcontainer's own `web.xml` changed to ignore `INCLUDE` and `FORWARD` dispatches or so?

Comment: web.xml had nothing but my catch-all servlet - without the /WEB-INF/jsp/* mapping, it would keep invoking my cath-all servlet and then SO.

Comment: Ok. Thx for all the help BalusC - I tried to get the filter working, but for now my eek servlet works.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy:

1. Put your **JSP** file inside **WEB-INF** folder.
2. In your servlet, perform a `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/path/your.jsp").forward(request, response);`