# How can I hide the JSP file in WEB-INF folder?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-inf, requestdispatcher

In a simple Java web application, for example imagine you have a servlet TestServlet.java. In deployment description ( web.xml ) you can for example map the request coming to say `/testpage`  to TestServlet so that when `/testapplication/testpage` is requested TestServlet handles the request. And you can for example write "Hello World" and send the response.

In directory structure ( the application that is deployed to the web server ), TestServlet.java will reside in:

```
webapps\testapplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\packagename\TestClass.java
```

which means there is no way to get to this file using the browser. ( Like entering a URL )

You can also get the request dispatcher and forward the request and response object to a JSP file like `.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp")`. But then the file will be in

```
webapps\testapplication\test.jsp
```

so connecting to http:\\server.com\test.jsp will also get this file.

I want to hide the file in WEB-INF folder so it can not be reached by the client except the mapping I have provided.

What is the appropriate way for doing this?

Comment: What do u mean by  hide the file in WEB-INF folder? .

Comment: I want the file to go under WEB-INF folder. The jsp file.

Comment: As usual BalusC gives the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229035/include-a-private-jsp-from-a-servlet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I want to hide the file in WEB-INF folder so it can not be reached by the client.*

Keep your jsp files under `WEB-INF` for example - `(WEB-INF/jsp)`, so that by default Web Containers does not allow resources under WEB-INF folder to be accessed directly by clients, but the `RequestDispatcher` can access it.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

---

Comment: But my question is, in java servlet, how should I give the path to the jsp file? Like getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/test.jsp") ? Is this the right way?

Comment: Your answer is not correct, if you correct it I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you @KorayTugay :). I missed out giving complete code snippet line.  Now I have corrected it.

Comment: "by defaul Web Containers [do] not allow resources under WEB-INF folder to be accessed directly" - this does not seem to be the case for Jetty. Jetty happily serves up everything under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsf, you can put this file in WEB-INF folder and use a navigation rule to mapping the request to the page. But if you are not, you can create a filter and map it to url "/test.jsp" using the `<url-pattern>` attribute and redirect to anywhere you want (like a page in WEB-INF).