# How to route ALL requests to a specific servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

Configuring servlets in `web.xml` usually follows this pattern:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/servletName/some/path/here
```

What configuration do I use if I want *all* requests to go to the same servlet?

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some/path/here
```

Comment: So, you basically want a front controller? This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/ Note that having a servlet on `/*` is a poor idea. How about requests on static content like img/css/js? This may be helpful as well then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513

Comment: Thanks, and +1 also for your answer there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Point your `<url-pattern>` in `web.xml` to your servlet like so:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```