# 404 Error accessing static content when defualt servlet is defined in web.xml

Tags: tomcat, servlets, default

I am running a webapp in a Tomcat 7 container, and am recieving 404 errors when attempting to access static content (.css, etc.).  Below is my directory structure:

- ROOT

  - META-INF
  - resources

    - css
  - WEB-INF

    - classes
    - lib

I have defined a default servlet in my deployment descriptor as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.HomeController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The HomeController servlet forwards the request to a .jsp, and the view is rendered properly.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("view.jsp").forward(request,
        response);
```

"view.jsp" has a link to a stylesheet (style.css) located in the css folder listed above.  However, because the servlet is configured as a default servlet, I am now not able to access the static content in the css folder, and any request for this stylesheet returns a 404 error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css" />
```

Is there any way around this?  What is the best method for serving up static resources, but still being able to define a default servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't homegrow your own default servlet. Use the servletcontainer's builtin default servlet. Your front controller should be mapped on a more specific URL pattern, e.g. `*.html` or `/pages/*`.

If your intent is to not change the URLs, then you should create an additional `Filter` class which is mapped on `/*` and just continues the chain when the `/resources/*` is requested and otherwise forward to the front controller servlet which is mapped on `/pages/*`.

E.g.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (uri.startsWith("/resources/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Goes to container's default servlet.
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages" + uri).forward(request, response);
}
```

And link your CSS just with the `/resources` path in the URL, exactly as you have in your public webcontent folder structure.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to accesss static resources when using default servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be linking css from resources path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: I believe the result would be the same as using ${pageContext.request.contextPath}