# JSP with CSS does not display the background image

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, tomcat

I have the following directory structure

[image: structure]
http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/7092/96816871.jpg

My CSS tries to use an image as a background

```
#search-text {
width: 213px;
height: 28px;
padding: 6px 0 0 7px;
border: none;
background: url(../images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
color: #000000;
```

}

and it doesn't work while other parts of css work fine.

Firebug shows that application tries to access image by URL _http://localhost:8080/images/img02.jpg and gets 404 error

When I try to access image directly I also get this error. Also I tried 
_http://localhost:8080/paygate/images/img02.jpg 
_http://localhost:8080/paygate/resources/images/img02.jpg 
...and this error doesn't stop follow me.

When I've changed my CSS file to the following

```
background: url(images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
```

warning appeared in webserver log:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/paygate/images/img02.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

and Firebug showed 404 error for URL _http://localhost:8080/**paygate**/images/img02.jpg

How should I organize my directory structure or what should I do to make my images accessible. Thank's!

P.S. I'm using springsource tc server as a webserver.

Comment: try using this location for image `../views/images/img02.jpg` hope it works

Answer (score 2):

According to your project structure, the .css file and images folder is in the same level, So:

```
background: url(images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
```

will work.

Comment: Nothing changed. Firebug: http://localhost:8080/paygate/images/img02.jpg 404 error and appeared warning in web server log
    WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/paygate/images/img01.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: This message indicates that the Spring DispatcherServlet is mapped to /images/img01.jpg (through a servlet-mapping element in your web.xml). It thus tries to find a URL mapping for this path in its configuration and doesn't find one. The images shouldn't be mapped to the dispatcher servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Static resources are supposed to be served by the container's default servlet. However whenever you map any servlet on an URL pattern of `/` or `/*` in your webapp, then the default servlet will be completely overridden. You don't want to have that. Map the Spring dispatcher servlet on a more specific URL pattern, e.g. `/app/*` or `*.html` or whatever. If you don't want to have changes in the URL, then you need to put static resources in a fixed folder like `/static` and create a `Filter` which will forward the non-static resources to the Spring dispatcher servlet.

#### See also:

- [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513) - Contains a code example