# include css inside a spring mvc java project

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How is this achieved, I have everything mapped from / to the dispatcher Servlet and the css is in the webapp folder. when clicking on the css link href in the source I get a tomcat error.

Do I need to create a @RequestMapping for css?

Comment: You should exclude static content from Spring request processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access static resources when using default servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Css are served without the need of dispatcher (unless you configure it to serve css). Just put them in some folder in your webapp dir and reference them as /YourAppContext/path-to-your-css in your pages.

For example in typical (non-maven) webapp it's inside WebContent/css

Assuming your app's context name is MyApp and you want to reference WebContent/css/main.css
you should put something like this in jsp:

```
<c:url value="/css/main.css" />
```

or uglier using

```
/MyApp/css/main.css
```

as your css url

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. I just needed to add <mvc:resources mapping="/csscontent/**" location="/csscontent/" />

Answer (score 0):

CSS are client files, not server files. All client files (CSS, Javascript, etc.) have nothing to do with Spring MVC, which acts on servlets (on the server). SO you add your CSS exactly the same way you would if you weren't using Spring MVC.

Comment: They come from the server, though, and because of the OP's mapping, are currently being processed by Spring (poorly). The server will act on whatever requests are given to it to handle, regardless of mimetype.

Comment: True, what I meant is that the "logic" contained in them have nothing to do with the servlets, and will be "processed" at runtime by the browser.