# Spring image files access cause 404 not found

Tags: spring

When I put below url which exists on Server, I get the 404 error

```
localhost/PDFDemo/resources/jquery/css/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png



Error 404--Not Found

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.

If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code `403 (Forbidden)` can be used instead. The `410 (Gone)` status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
```

I had same problem for javascript files and resolved the issue by putting below in web.xml

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

Are there equivalent codes for jsp and images which I can put in `contextConfigLocation`(eg : servlet.xml).

Comment: what path is your Spring dispatcher servlet mapped to?

Comment: <url-pattern>  value is  '/'. When I change it to '/*' 404 occurs on every page.

Comment: Have you declared `mvc:resources` in your configuration xml file? Please show that content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mapping the Spring Dispatcher Servlet to the root context, so Spring wants to handle every request (which isn't in itself a problem if you have it configured correctly).  Adding something like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/public-resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>
```

Modified for your environment should work.  See the documentation for allowing static resources to bypass Spring and go to the default servlet [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

You should also add this to your config so that Spring knows to use the Default Servlet.

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Also, answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet) may help you.