# web.xml How to forward to html file after using /*

Tags: html, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I am using a servlet which has this mapping (to a vaadin servlet actually)

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>my Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to make an exception for some html files that I have. It is ok if these are in a subfolder.

How do I do that? Is there a Tomcat-servlet to point to (in the  part) which handles file reads?

Rob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Is there a Tomcat-servlet to point to (in the part) which handles file reads?*

It's the [`DefaultServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html). As you can see in its [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html), its servlet name is `default`.

So, this should do, provided that those static files are in `/static` folder:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Beware however, older Tomcat versions have a security bug whereby all contents of `/WEB-INF` and `/META-INF` are publicly accessible when (ab)using the default servlet this way.

#### See also:

- [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513)

Comment: I am using tomcat 6, is that safe? Thanks for your complete answer :)

Comment: It's fixed since 6.0.30. See also [issue 50026](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026), reported by yours truly.