# why tomcat7.0.47 can not access static resources(js, css) while mapping a front controller servlet on an URL pattern of *.do or / or /*

Tags: java, css, spring, servlets, tomcat7

In fact, I am writing **a maven project with spring**.Everything is ok until I want to **import my css file**.Here is my web.xml(**only the servlet part**):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then I visit my page on this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello.do?method=reg
```

However, I have got a problem:**style.css is 404 Not Found**

so, I have searched some file and then I got a method:add some configuration in my servlet.xml(my servlet is **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

As you see my css file is under "/WEB-INF/resources/".But,the problem still exists.At last, I know one thing:

> static resources cannot be accessed while servlet is mapped on an URL pattern of  / or /*

So I change my **web.xml** to this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Finally, the problem is totally solved,but this makes me more puzzled,**why tomcat can not access static resources(js, css) while mapping a front controller servlet on an URL pattern of **.do or / or /***

**update(Dec 30 '13):**

My application is this:

```
MyApplication
pom.xml
src
    test
    main
       java
            com.roger.spring
                controller
                    UserController.java
                dao
                    impl
                        UserDaoImpl.java
                    UserDao.java
                domain
                    User.java
                service
                    impl
                        UserService.java
                    UserService.java
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                applicationContext.xml
                dao.xml
                db.properties
                mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
                service.xml
                web.xml
                pages
                    index.jsp
                    taglib.jsp
                    user
                         login.jsp
                         reg.jsp
                         profile.jsp
                 resources
                    css
                         style.css
                    js
                         calendar.js
```

Comment: This statement `static resources cannot be accessed while servlet is mapped on an URL pattern of / or /*` is wrong.

Comment: In fact I am not that clear about this, so I tried to find more articles about this these days.Finally, I find some, but it is a shame to say I cannot understand them totally.But I can tell you how I know this:[How to access static resources when using default servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8717371/2849157) and [Bug 50026 - DefaultServlet serves META-INF and WEB-INF from root when remapped on /folder/*](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026#c2).One thing I am sure is that when I use / or /* or \*.do I can not access my css file,but it wroks when I use /user/*.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler and rather cleaner to use the default servlet mapping - rather than the `/user/*` and the struts-like `*.do` mappings:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

All requests will now be sent through Spring MVC - including requests for static resources.

You should then amend your controller `@RequestMapping`s and remove the `*.do` too - so your URL becomes:

```
http://localhost:8080/hello?method=reg
```

Make sure you still have `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Then you should be able to serve static resources using `<mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />` without any problems.

Comment: I am sorry I reply late.To make sure,I have tried your method,but in fact, it doesn't work.

Comment: And for your point,I want to quote an answer for another question([How to access static resources when using default servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12345023/2849157)).The second answer shows that you shouldn't be mapping a front controller servlet on an URL pattern of / or /* at all.