# How to return images from web project?

Tags: java, servlets

I want return images that located under webcontent file from my dynamic web project.

And here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>WebDeneme</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>KH Web Services</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.kh.service</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>KH Web Services</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

But when I call http://cvksoft.com:8080/WebDeneme/images/deneme.jpg

Response is HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

what is my missing, what must I do to call image on my web project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple of things mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet)

What I have done is add this config to my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.images</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```