# How to process / URL while having default processing for /js,/css,

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

For a WebApp, I need to serve all .js, .css and all images from corresponding folders in my web app development tree ./js, ./css, ... through a default handling.
So any URL like

http://www.example.com/js/x.js

should be served straight from the static files in the war.

The main servlet should deal with all requests that are not for the above.
I need to be able to process requests like

http://www.example.com/PROJ/ELEM/WHATEVER

with the same unique main servlet.

So I thought I'd do this in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/css/*,/js/*,/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and map the main servlet like this to make some JSTL mods in a JSP file:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/*")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                  HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("test", "ok");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp")
                            .forward(request, response);        
    }
}
```

When I do this I end up in a recursive loop.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Check this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet

I think it will help you.

Comment: @RahulJain Thanks for the suggestion. The accepted answer to that question didn't work for me but the next one (with 30+ votes) did. Could you make it an answer, so I can vote on it and explain further? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation with same problem.
http://www.kuligowski.pl/java/rest-style-urls-and-url-mapping-for-static-content-apache-tomcat,5

Comment: This works for me. In summary: define a global filter where you detect the static paths and redirect it to the default servlet with a

**chain.doFilter**

then redirect all others to your smarter servlet(s) with a **forward**

Answer (score 0):

This is what already happens. There is a 'default servlet' that handles any request that isn't specifically mapped to an installed servlet.

Comment: Thanks @EJP - but my main servlet must be mapped to "/". Hence my issues.

Answer (score 0):

A simple variation on Rahul Jain's answer. You could do what spring MVC does for static resources : DispatcherServlet is a catch all, and it is configured to delegate to default servlet for a number or url. This may be interesting for a catch all servlet because it is often designed as a front controller that delegates actual serving to other controllers (be them servlets or not).

You can simply give the prefixes of urls that should serve static resources in a comma separated string in a context param of name `static_path_prefixes` and put that in your servlet :

```
String[] staticPathPrefixes;
RequestDispatcher defaultDispatcher;

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = hsr.getServletPath();
    for (String url: staticPathPrefixes) {
        if (path.startsWith(url)) {
            defaultDispatcher.forward(hsr, hsr1);
            return;
        }
    }
    super.service(hsr, hsr1);
}

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    String urls = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("static_path_prefixes");
    staticPathPrefixes = urls.split(" *, *");
    defaultDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().
            getNamedDispatcher("default");
}
```