# Grails error using HttpServletResponse to export file for download

Tags: grails, groovy, opencsv

I am using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) in my Grails application to export attributes from my Person domain class to CSV. I am receiving the following error, however:

Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
Message: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

From searching online, I think the answer may be to implement some responseComplete() method somewhere for the HttpServletResponse response. However, I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
def export = {
    def course = Course.get(params.id)
    if(course){
        def persons = course ? Person.findAllByCourse(course) : []


        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
           "attachment; filename=people.csv")
        response.contentType = "text/csv"
        def out = response.outputStream
        out.withWriter { writer ->

           String[] properties = new String[3]
           def csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer)
           persons.each { person ->

              properties[0] = person.firstName
              properties[1] = person.lastName
              properties[2] = person.email
              properties[3] = person.phone
              properties[4] = person.address1
              properties[5] = person.address2
              properties[6] = person.city
              properties[7] = person.state
              properties[8] = person.zip5

              csvWriter.writeNext(properties)
           }
           csvWriter.flush()
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you got a `render` or `redirect` being called anywhere (that's outside the above code)?

Comment: Try to use the gsp template for the CSV and standard model filled with data.

Comment: As I am a bit new to Grails, I am not sure what you're referring to when you say the gso template for CSV. Can you elaborate a bit or point to an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably stems from explicitly writing to the output stream in your controller, followed by the default behavior of GSP rendering upon returning from your action.  You might check [How to prevent Grails from rendering the default view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708654/how-to-prevent-grails-from-rendering-the-default-view) for another case of this, with a couple fixes.  I don't have grails on the machine I'm on currently to recreate the issue, but sounds like adding an explicit `return null` to at the end of the closure may help.  Or producing some token output or a 200 status code via `render`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this proprity String[] properties = new String[3] by String[] properties = new String[9].

It works for me.