# Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

I have an action that writes directly to the output stream. Sometimes I get the following to errors:

```
Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
Caused by getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

and this one:

```
Executing action [getImage] of controller [buddyis.ItemController] caused exception: Runtime error executing action
Caused by Broken pipe
```

How can I solve these problems? The action I use is listed below.

NOTE: I use Tomcat 7.0.42, if this is important!

```
def getImage() {
    byte [] imageByteArray = // some image bytes

    response.setHeader 'Content-disposition', "attachment; filename=\"${imageName}${imageExtension}\""
    response.setContentType("image/pjpeg; charset=UTF-8")
    response.contentLength = imageByteArray.size()
    response.outputStream.write(imageByteArray)
    response.outputStream.flush()
    response.outputStream.close()
    return
}
```

Comment: Try to render something (dummy) to index or render a status code and see if you still get the issue. You can start with `render(status: 200)` or at the least `render "Done"` etc before return.

Comment: Refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184603/grails-error-using-httpservletresponse-to-export-file-for-download).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting that error, however here is what I do that works everytime.

I don't call `.flush()` or `.close()`

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=\"${name}\"")
response.setContentLength(imageByteArray.size())
response.outputStream << imageByteArray
```

Using the above it was working fine, until I found out a user can cancel a download, which caused an exception. This is the full code I use instead of `response.outputStream << imageByteArray`:

```
    def outputStream = null
    try {
        outputStream = response.outputStream
        outputStream << imageByteArray

    } catch (IOException e){
        log.debug('Canceled download?', e)
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null){
            try {
                outputStream.close()
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.debug('Exception on close', e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use Tomcat 7.0.42, if this is important to the answer? Why ContentType "application/octet-stream"?

Comment: I think I'm using 7.0.39 so that shouldn't matter. As far as the content type - I allow for download/upload of multiple types of files. This seems to work for all.

Comment: Okay and what about .flush() and .close() why don't you need that?

Comment: From my experience Google Chrome arbitrary terminates connections sometimes. So, I would add catching the exception::if (e.getClass().name == 'org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException') {
                log.warn "Request was arbitrary terminated by the client: $e.cause"
            }

Comment: What @Andiry added was a feature of logging - its personal preference. It does not change the way it works. Answers should have the least amount of information possible to sufficiently answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue whilst running grails 2.5 on tomcat:7.0.55.3 and with the java-melody grails plugin installed. After uninstalling java-melody it worked just fine