# Servlet redirect

Tags: java, servlets, redirect

```
resp.sendRedirect("/myurl");
req.getSession().setAttribute("foo", "bar");
```

In this case, do I have access to the foo attribute after the redirect?
On generally speaking, a servlet is completely executed before the redirect is made or it stops it's execution after the redirect line?

Thanks

Comment: From my personal experience, it should be noted that after `sendRedirect` has been called, the response has been committed so any further modifications to the response will result in an exception being thrown. Therefore your function should `return` once you have invoked `sendRedirect`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committed/2125045#2125045

Comment: I agree with @Hamed; it's confusing to continue processing, although if you're not modifying the response, you *can*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It continues execution.

It's not a `return`, it just adds information to the response.

Answer (score 0):

after redirecting to that particular page, the control goes to that page and come back to old page and execute the req.getSession().setAttribute("foo", "bar"); also. this is the sendRedirect() bahaviour

Answer (score 0):

I found out a more generic approach that works for jsp files as well as for servlets.

```
String url = "http://google.com";

response.reset();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
response.setHeader("Location",url);
response.getWriter().close();
response.getWriter().flush();
```