# Stop further processing when redirecting in a filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have URLRewirteFilter which checks if requested domain starts with www. and redirects to no-www url. How can I stop futher processing (invoking JSF app, call servlets etc.) when request is to be redirected?
So far I have this:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String sn = req.getServerName().toLowerCase();
    if (sn.startsWith("www.")) {
        String url = "http://" + getDefaultDomain() + req.getContextPath() + req.getRequestURI();
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.reset();
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        resp.setHeader("Location", url);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just either add a `return` statement to the end of the `if`

```
if (sn.startsWith("www.")) {
    String url = "http://" + getDefaultDomain() + req.getContextPath() + req.getRequestURI();
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    resp.reset();
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    resp.setHeader("Location", url);
    return;
}
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

or add an `else`

```
if (sn.startsWith("www.")) {
    String url = "http://" + getDefaultDomain() + req.getContextPath() + req.getRequestURI();
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    resp.reset();
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    resp.setHeader("Location", url);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

#### See also:

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot (forward | sendRedirect | create session) after response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123514/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-forward-after-response-has-been-committe/2125045#2125045)

Comment: Basically, don't call `chain.doFilter`