# Servlet filter confusion, response redirect isn't happening

Tags: java, redirect, httpresponse, servlet-filters

I have an Authentication filter that's supposed to stop users from browsing to any pages where you need to be logged in for:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig fc;
    private final String indexURL = "/index.xhtml";
    private final String registerUrl = "/register/register.xhtml";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.fc = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        UserBean user = (UserBean) session.getAttribute("userBean");
        String requestUrl = req.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println("user is " + user);
        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println("username is " + user.getUsername());
            if (user.getUsername() == null || user.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                System.out.println("request url is " + requestUrl);
                if (!requestUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(indexURL) && 
                        !requestUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(registerUrl) && !requestUrl.startsWith("/javax.faces.resource")) {
                    //Redirect back to indexpage
                    System.out.println("request url is not for index/register/resource, it is: " + requestUrl);
                    resp.sendRedirect(indexURL);
                };
            }
        } else {
            resp.sendRedirect(indexURL);
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

It is actually printing what I expect, but it's not doing the redirect, this is (the last part of) my log info:

```
Info:   request url is /javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml
Info:   user is be.kdg.repaircafe.beans.UserBean@350af1bb
Info:   username is null
Info:   request url is /javax.faces.resource/repaircafe_logo.png.xhtml
Info:   user is be.kdg.repaircafe.beans.UserBean@350af1bb
Info:   username is null
Info:   request url is /welcome.xhtml
Info:   request url is not for index/register/resource, it is: /welcome.xhtml
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/welcome.xhtml] --> I just told you to redirect! Why are you doing this to me??
```

EDIT: After some debugging, I found out that the debugger hits the chain.doFilter() even after he redirected the response, why is he still forwarding me to welcome instead of index?

Comment: Is debug pointer is hitting `resp.sendRedirect(indexURL);
`?

Comment: if `requestUrl` and `indexURL` is same than I don't think it's going inside if.

Comment: If you redirect, you shouldn't call chain.doFilter(req, resp); right after.

Comment: It seems like filter get hit in loop when page is welcome.xhtml.

Comment: Yes the debug pointer hits the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by looking at another stackoverflow answer, if I just hit return after the redirect it will stop the filter from doing his forward.

[Stop further processing when redirecting in a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445903/stop-further-processing-when-redirecting-in-a-filter)

Comment: If you had read the comments, you woud have found out sooner: *If you redirect, you shouldn't call chain.doFilter(req, resp); right after*

Comment: I did read the comments, but you didn't supply a basis on why I can't do that. It seemed more of a hunch than a fact.