# How to serialize Java object into JSON and return it in servlet filter?

Tags: java, json, spring, servlets

I have this `javax.servlet.Filter` to check whether client is allowed to access API REST resource.

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN = "X-Access-Token";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("loginService")
    private ILoginService loginService;

    private void throwUnauthorized(ServletResponse res) throws IOException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

    }

    private void throwForbidden(ServletResponse res) throws IOException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        String accessToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
            throwUnauthorized(res);
        } else {
            AccountLoginData account = loginService.find(accessToken);
            if (account == null) {
                throwForbidden(res);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

it works but I would like to in these two `throw*()` methods write to the client JSON with appropriate information. In another part of this application I use these response message objects to inform client what happened.

For example, when record has not been found:

```
public class NotFoundResponseMessage extends ResponseMessage {

    public NotFoundResponseMessage(String message) {
        super(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 1, message);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class ResponseMessage {

    private int status;
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private String reason;

    public ResponseMessage(int status, int code, String message, String reason) {

        Assert.notNull(reason, "Reason must not be null.");
        Assert.isTrue(status > 0, "Status must not be empty.");

        this.status = status;
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.reason = reason;

    }
```

}

**My Question**

I would like to return JSON with serialized objects (`UnauthorizedResponseMessage` and `ForbiddenResponseMessage`) in my `javax.servlet.Filter` authorization / authentication filter. I use Spring Boot and Jackson library.

1. How can I **manually** serialize `ResponseMessage` into its JSON representation?
2. How can I write out this JSON back to the client in my filter class?

**Edit 1:**

```
private void throwUnauthorized(ServletResponse res) throws IOException {

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.reset();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.getWriter().write("{\"foo\":\"boo\"}");

}
```

Now I can write out JSON but HTTP 500 is returned, because:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:544)
```

Comment: afaik you'd do `chain.doFilter(req, res);` only in the authenticated case. Otherwise things down the chain try to add a regular (duplicate) response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8445927/995891

Answer (score 3):

Using `Jackson` convert `Object` to `JSON`, the following is an example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String Json =  mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: Why is it answer down-voted? What is wrong with it (it works).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the complete solution is the following:

```
try {
    restResponse = service.validate(httpReq);
} catch (ForbiddenException e) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ResponseObject object = new ResponseObject();
    object.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    object.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    object.setError("Forbidden");
    object.setTimestamp(String.valueOf(new Date().getTime()));
    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResp.reset();
    httpResp.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    httpResp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    String json =  mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    response.getWriter().write(json);
    return;
}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Just throw your exceptions from the filter and annotate the thrown exception with `@ResponseStatus`. This way it automatically gets translated to the given http error code. (you can also define the error message)

Code example:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Error while trying to add the feed.")
public class AddFeedException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 290724913968202592L;

    public AddFeedException(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this I use in controllers but this exception handling in `javax.servlet.Filter` doesn't work because it is outside the Springs `servletDispatcher`...