# How to return response as Json from spring filter?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

In spring rest, I need to send authentication error from `doFilter()` of my filter class. In response, I need to send json with fields like status, message, and errorCode. Kindly suggest how to achieve this. We are not using spring boot. Below is the sample response of the Authentication error:

```json
{   
    "responseCode":" Error code",
    "responseMessage": "Some Error message",
    "responseStatus":"Fail"
}
```

Inside `doFilter()`, U am validating the token, if it's not valid I need to send the above sample response.

Comment: Create and populate a java.util. Map and write it to the ServletResponse as detailed here: https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-json-response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize Java object into JSON and return it in servlet filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584733/how-to-serialize-java-object-into-json-and-return-it-in-servlet-filter)

Answer (score 30):

Assuming you have Jackson's `ObjectMapper` exposed as a Spring bean, you could use the following for a `OncePerRequestFilter`:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {

        Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();
        errorDetails.put("message", "Invalid token");

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        mapper.writeValue(httpServletResponse.getWriter(), errorDetails);
    }
}
```

For a plain servlet `Filter`, the solution would be much the same:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                         ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException {

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        Map<String, Object> errorDetails = new HashMap<>();
        errorDetails.put("message", "Invalid token");

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

        mapper.writeValue(httpServletResponse.getWriter(), errorDetails);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

The above examples rely on constructor injection and use Lombok's [`@RequiredArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor.html) to generate a constructor that receives values for the fields marked with `final`.

You also could replace the `Map<String, Object>` for any arbitrary POJO, according to your needs.

Comment: Thnx, It helped

Comment: it worked, Thanks