# what happens when I configure a servlet before a filter in tomcat's web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

In tomcat for a certain url, I want to skip all the filters and execute a servlet and I thought placing the servlet before the filter will to as I expected but still the filters behind the servlet mappings are executing. Am I doing anything wrong?

For instance, this is my web.xml

```xml
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>APIRedirection</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.APIRedirection</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>APIRedirection</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/abc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

So when the incoming url contains "/abc/" I want my servlet to execute and skip the filters. I placed my servlet before all the filters but still the filters are getting executed when the incoming url contains '/abc/'.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768717/how-to-get-a-request-on-controller-for-endpoint-which-is-defined-as-default-serv/56768905#56768905

Comment: there are few default filters which doesn't provide this facility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of servlet before filter.

If servlets url mapping qualify filters url mapping then filter is executed before servlet.
I got your requirement you just don't want to hit Filters for certain urls.
a. If your application is still in starting phase, you can configure as given below

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/filtered/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/filtered/servlet2</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/filtered/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And the servlet url for which you want to bypass filter

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/unfiltered/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2. If your application is already developed, and you configured a filter already with mapping `/*` then you can not skip that filter being executed. But you can add one more filter before that filter. Here filter order plays an important role,[(reference for filter order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938050/what-will-the-the-order-in-which-filters-will-be-called) you can perform same functionality which you expected from a servlet. In your filter you just have to break filter chain and send response as given below

```java
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,ServletException 
{
    //your business logic
    // construct responseToSend
    response.getOutputStream().write(responseToSend);
    return;
}
```

[For more information of breaking filter chain refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445903/stop-further-processing-when-redirecting-in-a-filter)